# I am new to TypeScript and I cannot figure out which type to assign to the returning value of a function which can be a string or boolean

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

TypeScript: Given value of function is a number but returning value can be a string or boolean.

In this case the returning value type is **Any** which I do not want to use:

```
    var getValue = (myVal: number) => {
        if(myVal > 5){
            return true;
        }
        return "200 OK";
    }
```

In this case the returning value type is **Boolean** which cause error for the string:

```
    var getValue = (myVal: number):boolean => {
        if(myVal > 5){
            return true;
        }
        return "200 OK";
    }
```

In this case the returning value type is **String** which cause error for the boolean:

```
    var getValue = (myVal: number):string => {
        if(myVal > 5){
            return true;
        }
        return "200 OK";
    }
```

I have used the type **Any** in this scenario but as it is not a good practice so I just wanted to know which type can be used instead of **Any**.

Comment: use `string|boolean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union | like this...

```
    var getValue = (myVal: number):boolean | string => {
        if(myVal > 5){
            return true;
        }
        return "200 OK";
    }
```